# How to search through List<string>?

Tags: c#, list

I have database with table tbl_employee. In the table I store usernames. I use the following code to save all the usernames into a List:

```
string name = txtUsername.Text;       
List<string> lst = new List<string>();

NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=db;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;"); 

conn.Open();
string sql = "SELECT username FROM tbl_employee";
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);  
NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();  
while (dr.Read())
{
    lst.Add(dr.GetString(0));
}
```

Now, my question is how can I search through my list (lst) to see if the users input from textbox (name) exists in the list?

I have tried this:

```
if (lst.FindString(name)) 
    //Says it has some invalid arguments
```

And this:

```
if (lst.Exists(element => element == name)) 
    //It says name exists even though it doesn't
```

Comment: Filter in the database instead. `SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM tbl_employee WHERE username=@username`

Comment: @TimSchmelter is absolutely correct... what if you had a million records that you pull across the wire needlessly?

Comment: In your code `lst` is a `List<string>`, which doesn't have a `FindString` method (and there's no extension method I know of with that name), so you should have gotten a "*does not contain a definition*" error, not "*invalid arguments*". However, there is `FindString` method on the `ListBox` class. Just to be clear, what exactly is `lst` and is it the same object in both snippets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use `Contains`:

```
if (lst.Contains(name)) ...
```

But if this is *all* you're doing with the list, I'd recommend changing this code so it queries the `tbl_empoyee` table directly from the database. I'm not familiar with the `NpgsqlCommand` but it should look a bit like this:

```
bool result = false;
string sql = "SELECT username FROM tbl_employee WHERE username = :name";
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);  
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", name);
NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();  
while (dr.Read())
{
    result = true; // record found
}
```

Or like this (following *Tim Schmelter*'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415075/how-search-through-liststring-in-c/23415098#comment35880622_23415075)):

```
string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_employee WHERE username = :name";
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);  
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", name);
int found = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();  // 1 = found; 0 = not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `lst.Contains(name)`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks quys! I changed it to count, as you suggested. Here is my final code:

```
string name = txtUsername.Text;       

NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=db;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;"); 

conn.Open();
string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_employee WHERE username = @val1";
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);  
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", name);
var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
int i = Convert.ToInt32(result);
if (i != 0)
{
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(name, Persist.Checked);
}
else
{
    lblMessage.Text = "Invalid username or password";
 }
```